# return redis values in the middle of a foreach loop?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

Wondering if it is even possible to return values from my redis cache while i am performing a PHP foreach loop?

I might be over thinking this...

essentially i have a MySql instance and a redis instance.

my MySql instance returns the following:

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:6 [▼
    "user_id" => 2
    "short_url_key" => "aQpjoM"
    "original_url" => "www.domain.com/"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "created_at" => "2017-03-11 08:19:02"
    "updated_at" => "2017-03-11 08:19:02"
  ]
  1 => array:6 [▼
    "user_id" => 2
    "short_url_key" => "olW7uN"
    "original_url" => "www.domain.com/products/"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "created_at" => "2017-03-11 09:05:23"
    "updated_at" => "2017-03-11 09:05:23"
  ]
  2 => array:6 [▼
    "user_id" => 2
    "short_url_key" => "u4rjLA"
    "original_url" => "www.domain.com/products/asdf"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "created_at" => "2017-03-11 09:05:56"
    "updated_at" => "2017-03-11 09:05:56"
  ]
  3 => array:6 [▼
    "user_id" => 2
    "short_url_key" => "fOuOju"
    "original_url" => "www.domain.com/"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "created_at" => "2017-03-11 09:06:30"
    "updated_at" => "2017-03-11 09:06:30"
  ]
  4 => array:6 [▼
    "user_id" => 2
    "short_url_key" => "XmSBTK"
    "original_url" => "www.domain.com/xyz"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "created_at" => "2017-03-11 09:18:54"
    "updated_at" => "2017-03-11 09:18:54"
  ]
]
```

Now My Redis instance stores the short_url_key, the original_url & I store the visits their as well (which is what i am trying to return along with this data)
The visits just incriments on my redis key but would love to return this data along as well... Trying to think of how i can do that as part of my PHP loop? Or is their something I am not thinking of?

ideally I would like to append each of these arrays with the visits count from my redis instance.

```
"visits" => 22
```

update: I am able to loop through and return all the values... but now i am not sure how to merge that into the other array..

```
    foreach ($datas as $data)
    {
        echo Cache::get('short:' . $data['short_url_key'] . ':visits');
    }
    exit();
```

Cheers

Citti

Comment: i should say to lookup visits my redis key is: key:$shortUrl:visits  ... so i would need the value returned in these arrays to lookup the visits.... Maybe i a thinking about storing this all wrong as well

Answer (score 0):

ok I was clearly overthinking this - I ended up appending to the array like below. Worked like a charm. cheers.

```
    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {   
        // will switch short_url_key to visits when i know they line up correctly
        $data[$key][$value['short_url_key']] = Cache::get('short:' . $value['short_url_key'] . ':visits');
    }
```